# Variable defined in a function, needed within a function within this function - Python

Tags: python, function, global-variables, variable-assignment

I need to define a variable within a function and use it in a function that is within the original function. For example,

```
def go_to_next_function():
    globvar = 0
    def add_one_to_globvar():
        global globvar  
        for i in range(10):
            globvar += 1
            print(globvar)
    add_one_to_globvar()
go_to_next_function()
```

Now I know if `globvar` is defined outside all of the functions then it would work, but I want it to be defined inside the `go_to_next_function()` function. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: python2 or python3? In python3 you can use `nonlocal`.

Comment: It is in Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python3.x, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword rather than `global` and your function should work.

If you're on python2.x, you're stuck with old hacks like putting the value in a container and mutating *that*.  It's an ugly hack (which is why `nonlocal` was added in the first place):

```
def go_to_next_function():
    closure_var = [0]
    def add_one():
        closure_var[0] += 1
        print closure_var[0]
    add_one()
go_to_next_function()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Python 3